# How to remember previously saved form data for subsequent requests

Tags: java, forms, servlets

I have the code below in a servlet (page1) and I want after pressing Save to go to a second servlet (page2), read the content written in the form of page1 and append them in a radio group like this:

```
Question [i]: question  (i increases every time a question is added in page2)
radiobutton1 (radio1)
radiobutton2 (radio2)
radiobutton3 (radio3)
```

The point is every time I fill the form below, the data shall be added below data that have been saved previously.

Could you suggest some sample code for servlet page2?

Thanks a lot.

```
out.println("<form  id=\"form1\" action = \"page2\" method = \"POST\" >");            
        out.println("<input type=\"text\" name=\"question\"><br />");
        out.println("<input type=\"text\" name=\"radio1\"><br />");
        out.println("<input type=\"text\" name=\"radio2\"><br />");
        out.println("<input type=\"text\" name=\"radio3\"><br />");
        out.println("<input type = \"submit\" value = \"Save\">");
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're concretely asking, but I can at least tell that developing with JSP/Servlet would become so much more straight forward if you put HTML code in JSP files and Java code in Java (servlet) classes.

Comment: I agree, but I was asked to do so...
What I ask above, is how can I complete the form of page1 and pressing Save add these data in page2.

Comment: Yes, the requirement was understood, but it's unclear what exactly your concrete problem is. Is it collecting the request parameters? Is it printing the collected request parameters? Both tasks are also fairly obvious in such way that I'm just unsure if that's really a problem to you and how exactly. Editing your question to include some relevant servlet code wherein you're trying to accomplish those tasks would also be helpful.

Comment: The problem is that I get the request.getParameter from the form but I'm stack on how to print them without losing the previous saved data, and second how to add the question number [i] every time a set of data is saved.

Comment: Okay, your concrete problem is now understood. I fixed the question title and posted an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use either `<input type="hidden">` or the session scope to remember previously saved data. E.g.

```
<input type="hidden" name="question1answer" value="42" />
```

or

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("question1answer", 42);
```

The passed data is the subsequent request available as

```
String question1answer = request.getParameter("question1answer");
```

or

```
Integer question1answer = (Integer) request.getSession().getAttribute("question1answer");
```

The disadvantage of hidden inputs is that it produces quite some boilerplate code and that the enduser can easily guess/manipulate it. The disadvantage of the session scope is that it's shared across all requests within the same session (and thus may interfere when the enduser has the same page open in multiple browser windows/tabs). To combine best of both worlds, you can on 1st request generate a long and unique key which you use as a key to store all the associated data in the session scope and pass that key as hidden request parameter.

E.g. in first request

```
String key = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
request.setAttribute("key", key);
List<Answer> answers = new ArrayList<Answer>();
request.getSession().setAttribute(key, answers);
// ...
answer.add(question1answer);
```

and in HTML

```
<input type="hidden" name="key" value="${key}" />
```

and in all subsequent requests

```
String key = request.getParameter("key");
request.setAttribute("key", key);
List<Answer> answers = (List<Answer>) request.getSession().getAttribute(key);
// ...
answers.add(question2answer); // question3answer, question4answer, etc.
```

Comment: Thanks BalusC for the response, although I am a bit confused on how to use it...
Where does the subsequent request code has to be added?
Could you please give me some more info? Thank you.

Comment: Just in "the next form". So the form of question 2 should remember the answer of question 1 as hidden value. And the form of question 3 should remember the answer of questions 1 and 2 as hidden values. Etcetera. Makes sense, right?

Comment: This makes sense yes. So I should only add the code from String key and below to the page with the form (page1)?

Comment: In case of using a session attribute along with a key, the hidden input should be present in all forms. I have edited the answer to clarify that part a bit more. Sorry, I expected that the remainder was obvious enough for you.

Comment: No problem, I'm sorry...
The thing that doesn't make sense is that I only have one form for adding questions, so how the subsequent requests are made?

Comment: With my answer, it actually doesn't matter if you have only 1 or more subsequent requests. If you have only 1 (which is presumably that `<form action="page2">` form), then that's also fine.